# How does Steve escape from the building in Venice

Tags: plot-explanation, the-italian-job

In the movie *Italian Job*, in Venice, after the explosion when the safe drops into the river below, Charlie, Left Ear and John submerge themselves in the water to crack open the safe. Handsome Rob and Napster escape both with the dummy case via a speed boat. But Steve, who was upstairs painting the PoP and planting the explosive on the apartment ceiling just below the safe, is not shown escaping from the apartment. How did he escape? This is Venice, so roads are out! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

All attention was focused on the boat and on the dummy safe.  Steve would have had to have been a little sneaky to avoid the guys in the house if they immediately ran down to his floor, but presumably he was packed up and ready to go by the time the floor blew and he could have more or less made it out the front door and just walked away.

Comment: You do realize this was scene was shot in Venice, and the building had it's front door opening towards the river.

Comment: That's not actually how Venice works. Recall the opening scene in St. Marco's Square where John buys the necklace. You can get around Venice completely on foot, and the houses are not completely water-locked. It's the back-door that faces the canal, but that's neither here nor there, there's a door that leads out into a pedestrian walkway somewhere in the house.

Comment: Hmm.. that is a good point.